# Preprocessor #define tag on Objective-C non-Macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, preprocessor-directive

This probably isn't possible but wanted to verify as I cant find anything on the web about it.  Given an Objective-C call like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", var1, var2];
```

I would like to redefine it using something like this:

```
#define [NSString stringWithFormat(...)] //i realize this is not a macro but can //it be done ?
NSlocalizedString([NSString stringWithFormat(...)],@"comment"]);
```

Is this possible ?

UPDATE: Let me explain what i want.  I have inherited code that is not localized.  95% of the calls look like this:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", stringValue1,stringValue2];

I had a brainstorming idea wondering if i could 'redefine' stringWithFormat to use NSLocalizedString macro to localize the string. I wanted to do this in the prefix header so that all stringWithFormat calls would be redefined to NSLocalizedString macro first.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what your macro is, and what you're trying to accomplish with it. Could you clarify by giving a couple examples of what you want to use in the source code and what you want the preprocessor to transform it into?

Comment: i updated the response.  Just looking for a way to call NSLocalizedString on all the stringWtihFormat calls in one shot from the prefix header perhaps.

Comment: It would be better to just do a find and replace to change them all.

Comment: im scared im going to break code.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying really hard to avoid doing a find + replace - the best way forward is to just take the hit and do the manual work of a find + replace

Comment: Redefining `stringWithFormat:` with a macro is about 1000x more likely to break code than doing a find and replace.

Comment: got it, ok thanks just needed the ok from you guys.